# Upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 9 Fails

Tags: angular, angular9

I am running into a bunch of issues when trying t upgrade from angular 7 to Angular 9. When i try and do an ng update --all i get the following errors.

```
 Package "@agm/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "@agm/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "7.2.16" (extended), would install "9.1.6").
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "7.2.16", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.16", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.16" (extended), would install "9.1.6").
                  Package "angular2-toaster" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "angular2-toaster" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")           Package "angular2-toaster" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "bootstrap" has a missing peer dependency of "popper.js" @ "^1.16.0".
                  Package "igniteui-angular-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "igniteui-angular-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "igniteui-angular-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "igniteui-angular-core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "igniteui-angular-core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.6")
                  Package "igniteui-angular-core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.1.
                  Package "igniteui-angular-gauges" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "
                  Package "igniteui-angular-gauges" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^8.0.0", would install
                  Package "igniteui-angular-gauges" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0", would install "9.× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
```

then when i run  ng update --all --force

it produce some minor errors like

```
> Updates Angular Material to v8
    Could not find TypeScript project for project: my-app-e2e
```

when i run ng serve i get this

```
Warning: Entry point 'ng2-slim-loading-bar' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/DevSys/Documents/GitHub/Angular-CRM/Angular-7-CRM/node_modules/rxjs/Observable'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/animations : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/common : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/core/testing : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : module as esm5
Compiling ag-grid-angular : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : module as esm5
Compiling angular-font-awesome : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/forms : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/common/http : module as esm5
Error: Error on worker #7: Error: Failed to find exported name of node (CommonModule = (function () {
    function CommonModule() {
    }
    return CommonModule;
}())) in 'C:/Users/DevSys/Documents/GitHub/Angular-CRM/Angular-7-CRM/node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.es5.js'. 
    at Object.findExportedNameOfNode (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\find_export.js:35:19)
    at LogicalProjectStrategy.emit (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:228:38)
    at ReferenceEmitter.emit (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:71:44)
    at Object.toR3Reference (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\util.js:192:31)
    at NgModuleDecoratorHandler._toR3Reference (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:417:31)
    at C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:197:72
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NgModuleDecoratorHandler.analyze (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:197:38)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.analyzeTrait (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:345:40)
    at analyze (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:297:58)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:194:27)
    at C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:54:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:292:57)
    at step (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:139:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:120:57)
    at C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:109:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DevSys\Documents\GitHub\Angular-CRM\Angular-7-CRM\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:286:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
```

So i am a bit confused what causes this and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

there are some updates you need to do is not just a command, so to avoid errors, follow the official upgrade recommendations which says: do an upgrade from 7 to 8 then from 8 to 9, by following these instructions here: https://update.angular.io/#7.0:9.0